# Querydsl case when in where clause

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Am looking for example on use case when condition in where clause on querydsl.

SELECT column1, column2 FROM viewWhatever WHERE CASE 
WHEN column1 == 'b' THEN account_location = ?
WHEN column1 =='m' THEN location_area = ?

I just recently start using querydsl I can't figure out how to represent above query in querydsl case builder expression. 
I found examples for use in select clause but couldn't find much for use in where clause.

Comment: You didn't look at the official documentation then? http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.1/reference/html/ch03.html#d0e1586

Comment: @AlanHay that is for select clause`i am looking for samples using in where clause/predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a CASE statement?

```
SELECT 
   column1, column2 
FROM 
   viewWhatever 
WHERE 
   (column1 == 'b' AND account_location = ?)
OR
   (column1 =='m' AND location_area = ?)
```

Can obviously be easily represented in QueryDSL.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i did do this alternative, few hrs ago.